# How to clear value in QDateTimeEdit?

Tags: python, qt, datetime, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to set empty value to datetimeedit widget (`01.01.00 0:00` is not really what I want to see). Using `dtwidget.setDateTime(QDateTime())` or `dtwidget.clear()` is not affected. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

You may get default value from QDateTimeEdit class.

```
QDateTime dateTime=QDateTimeEdit().dateTime();
```

It is 01.01.2000 00:00.

Next use setDateTime() method.

Answer (score -3):

Short answer is *No you cannot.*

Here's the long answer.

You cannot set the date to `00.00.0000 00:00`. Because it makes no damn sense. By default, it shows an unknwon date-time as 12:00 AM of the first day of the first month of year 0000.

If you really badly want to show "00.00.00 0:00", then do this: `dt.setDisplayFormat( "00.00.00 0:00" )`. What's the problem with this? Yeah, it shows `00.00.00 0:00` for any date-time you set. You'll have to set a sensible format once the user starts interacting with your widget or you want to set a valid date-time.

So you want some crappy behaviour from standard Qt widgets, subclass them and implement your own code.